# Everything I am requesting is all on same line in listbox

Tags: vb.net

So when I click grab I want it to download all the stuff on the txt file located on the website link. So I managed to acomplish that but! When it downloads it say there are 4 lines of text it puts all 4 lines on the same line.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim Proxies As String = client.DownloadString("website url")
ListBox1.Items.Add(Proxies)
```

Keep in mind its in the private sub of my button. I also imported System.net

Comment: `ListBox1.Items.Add(Proxies)` adds 1 item - that string.  If you want the data in the one string added individually, you first have to split it into pieces so you can add as many items as it represents.

Comment: Thanks I understood that perfectly time to start working on a fix.

Comment: You may want to check that the real string (that looks anonymized) doesnt include NewLine characters to make splitting easier (and accurate)